# Static Friction work and Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy

I have this problem:

A 4.0 kg block is given an initial speed of 8.0 m/s at the bottom of a 20° incline.  The 
frictional  force  that  retards  its motion  is 15.0 N.    (a)  If  the block  is directed up  the 
incline, how far does it move before stopping?  (b)Will it slide back down the incline?

I've managed to get part (a) which was 4.51m but I'm not sure how to start part (b)..

The coefficient of Kinetic Friction was 0.407

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd like to draw your attention to what our [FAQ](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq) says about homework-like questions: *"Physics - Stack Exchange is not a homework help site. If you have a question about a homework problem, or any problem of an educational nature, narrow it down to the specific concept that is giving you trouble and ask about that. You can find more [information about acceptable homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) on our meta site"*. There is a good conceptual questions here. Can you edit this to *be* that question?

Answer (score 2):

Some potentially useful hints/questions:

1. When the ball gets to the top of its trajectory, it is no longer moving.
2. Draw a free body diagram for when the ball is at the top.
3. Under what condition on the forces will it move back down after stopping at the top?